# How to define a type that corresponds to Map[String, Option[String]]?

Tags: scala

Given the following method that takes a `Map[String, Option[String]]` parameter:

```
def myMethod(m: Map[String, Option[String]]) = {
  ...
}
```

how to define a new type `MyMap` that implements `Map[String, Option[String]]` so that the method looks like this:

```
def myMethod(m: MyMap) = {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`type MyMap = Map[String, Option[String]]`

Comment: This is hardly an answer. In a comment on a now-deleted (much better) answer, the OP says he wants to be able to create instances of `MyMap`. and this answer should at the very least explain why `new MyMap` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a type alias, for instance

```
type MyMap = Map[String, Option[String]]
```

A bit more general is the inclusion of a type parameter,

```
type MyMap[T] = Map[T, Option[T]]
```

Then the type may be instantiated for instance to `String`,

```
val a: MyMap[String] = Map("a"->Some("aa"))
a: MyMap[String] = Map(a -> Some(aa))
```

As of defining a method, note

```
def myMethod[T](m: MyMap[T]) = m.keys.size
myMethod: [T](m: MyMap[T])Int
```

and

```
def myMethodStr(m: MyMap[String]) = m.keys.size
myMethodStr: (m: MyMap[String])Int
```